# How to find if the data is a str or int in List

Tags: python

If I have a list as below:

```
samplist= [3,4,5,'abc']
```

How can I find out whether which index is a str or Int.I want to concatenate a string s='def' with the string 'abc' which is available in the list.

Assume that I am not aware I don't know anything about the string, neither the name nor its index in list. All i know is there is a string in the list samplist and I want to loop through and find it out so that it can be concatenated with string s='def'/.

Comment: use `isdigit()` maybe?

Comment: @shaktimaan, `isdigit()` can only be used for `str`, `unicode`, `bytes`, `bytearray`, ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for i in xrange(len(samplist)):
    if isinstace(samplist[i], str):
        samplist[i] += 'def'
```

Answer (score 0):

`type()` command also works:

```
>>> list = [1, 2, 'abc']
>>> type(list)
<class 'list'>
>>> type(list[1])
<class 'int'>
>>> type(list[2])
<class 'str'>
>>> type(list[2]) is str
True
>>> type(list[1]) is str
False
```

Comment: `isinstance` is a better approach in here.check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1549854/2276527) out

Comment: @shaktimaan Yes isinstance takes care of inheritance as well, but I doubt that would be necessary here.